# AngularJS directive for mobile navigation

Tags: angularjs, mobile, angularjs-directive, navigation, angularjs-bindings

I'm trying to built an AngularJS directive for toggling my mobile nav but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

The directive

```
app.directive('mobileDirective', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs){
      element.bind('onclick', function(){
        var status = element[0].className = "is-o";
        if(status){
          element[0].className = ".mobile-nav-toggle mobile-nav";
        }else{
          element[0].className = ".mobile-nav-toggle mobile-nav is-o";
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

The index.html

```
  <header data-ng-controller="navController">
    <div class="header-position">
      <a href="/" class="logo img-responsive"><img src="./assets/images/codehan_logo_raw.svg" class="mobile-logo" /></a>
      <nav id="nav" class="site-nav">
        <ul>
          <li data-ng-repeat="item in menu_items">
            <a data-ng-class="{ active: isActive('/{{item.name}}')}" href="{{item.name}}">{{item.name}}</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div class="mobile-nav-toggle mobile-directive"><span></span></div>
    </div>
    <div id="m-nav" class="mobile-nav mobile-directive">
      <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="item in menu_items">
          <a data-ng-class="{ active: isActive('/{{item.name}}')}" href="{{item.name}}">{{item.name}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>
```

With jQuery it looks like this and works fine

```
function mobileNav(){
  $('.mobile-nav-toggle').on('click', function(){
    var status = $(this).hasClass('is-o');
    if(status){
      $('.mobile-nav-toggle, .mobile-nav').removeClass('is-o');
    }else{
      $('.mobile-nav-toggle, .mobile-nav').addClass('is-o');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: you're using `mobile-directive` as class name. However, it is restricted to use as `attribute`. change one of them and try.

Comment: changed it.. still not working :(

Comment: can you please provide a plunker that reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0):

For the record (I know this is ancient) I'm pretty sure the problem might have been this line;

`var status = element[0].className = "is-o";`

You're setting `status` and `element[0].classname` to `"is-o"`, instead it should read;

`var status = element[0].className === "is-o";`

Meaning `status` equall whatever the result of `element[0].className === "is-o"` is.. I'm not convinced that's a solution as such but for such an old post I'm not even sure why I'm pointing this mistake out.